# How to insert data to the same ID within the week but adds another ID on the next week

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Good day!

I need your help again.

I am working on a daily report table that will allow the user to update the table everyday from Monday to Friday and adds automatically the total.
I don't know how I can get the ID and add it to the same row.

[image: Actual Table]

Here's the actual table. 
The first 4 is what we need to happen.
Below that is the problem when I'm adding new data it is not updating the first for.

Here's my new_report_phone.php..

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['addphone'])){
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $role = $_POST['role'];
        $prev_total = $_POST['prev_week'];
        $mon = $_POST['monday'];
        $tue = $_POST['tuesday'];
        $wed = $_POST['wednesday'];
        $thur = $_POST['thursday'];
        $fri = $_POST['friday'];
        $total = $mon + $tue + $wed + $thur + $fri;

include '../../db_config/connection.php';

                $sql = "INSERT INTO bocc_daily_phone (report_date, role, prev_week, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, total) VALUES ('$date', '$role', '$prev_total', '$mon', '$tues', '$wed', '$thur', '$fri', '$total')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header("location:../bocc_automation.php?message=$role have been added");
} else {
    $error = $conn->error;
     header("location:../new_report_phone.php?err=$error");
}

$conn->close();

}

?>
```

The Idea is to update the table everyday for the same ROLES. And on the next week the table for Mon-Fri will be blank and will get the Previous Week's total.
Can anyone help me make this happen. I would really appreciate to learn from you guys.
Once I was able to do it with your help I will be adding date filter to us the view old reports.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the form to update your data ?

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the data in **update form**
add this code to your post

```
$sql = "UPDATE bocc_daily_phone SET total = monday + tuesday + wednesday + thursday + friday WHERE id = ".$_POST['id'];
```